# How Can I create geo-referenced PCD map with KITTI Dataset Ground Truth Data

Tags: dataset, mapping, ros, kitti, pcdata

I created PCD map with KITTI dataset Ground Truth.I want to localize with this map and KITTI GNSS data.
The position and orientation values starts from zero in ground truth dataset so I created pcd which is starts from zero. When I start localization part with GNSS and this map, I reset the position data from gnss to zero. In other words, I accept the first position data in the raw data as origin and project it with UTM on the ground truth map and this is how I localize on the map with GNSS.

However, the location where I am localized with GNSS data is initially approximately 0.5-1 meter, and then the error continues to increase. At this point I infer that the origin value I used to localize to me is incorrect.

Is the position and orientation of the first data in the Ground Truth data in the real world equal to the first value of the GNSS data in the raw data? Do these two data start at the same time and at the same point?
If not, how can I create a Georeferenced map with Ground Truth data?